# Installing Atom packages with git port blocked

Tags: c++, git, package, atom-editor

I'm trying to install the autocomplete-clang plugin for atom. Unfortunately my company firewall blocks the 9418 port which is used by the git:// protocol.

I'm able to install plugins which use https:// URL to clone git repos and dependencies but when I try to install autocomplete-clang I get the following error :

```
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git://github.com/Kev/clang-flags.git) https://github.com/Kev/clang-flags.git
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/Kev/clang-flags.git Cloning into bare repository '~/.atom/.apm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-Kev-clang-flags-git-1a523481'...
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/Kev/clang-flags.git fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/Kev/clang-flags.git github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Connection timed out
npm ERR! Linux 3.11-2-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/clement/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/clement/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/tmp/d-115117-10848-qhdhe7/package.tgz" "--target=0.21.0" "--arch=x64"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.3.0
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: Cloning into bare repository '~/.atom/.apm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-Kev-clang-flags-git-1a523481'...
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Connection timed out
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/apm-install-dir-115117-10848-1qirptl/npm-debug.log
```

I tried to add this to my gitconfig:

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

I also redirected traffic from port 9418 to port 80

```
# iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 24948 packets, 4967K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9418 redir ports 80
```

but it doesn't work. Did I miss something ? How could I bypass this block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first if you cannot instruct git to use https instead of git, all the time:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

The [OP Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292876/opera) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559084/installing-atom-packages-with-git-port-blocked/28559403?noredirect=1#comment45564733_28559403) the issue to be linked to [`atom/apm` 106](https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/106), related to [`npm/npm` 5257](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5257#issuecomment-60404802):

> `apm` not respecting `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

Opera adds:

> I edited the [`add-remote-git.js`](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/cache/add-remote-git.js) file (now containing the code that is referred to in [`atom/apm` 106](https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/106)) and added the replace call suggested in the last comment.

Comment: That's what I used to edit my gitconfig. Just tried it again, doesn't work.

Comment: @Opera what version of Git are you using?

Comment: $ git --version
git version 1.8.5.1

Comment: @Opera That should work unless Atomio uses another git internally (jgit? libgit2?). Is there any .gitconfig anywhere in that tool?

Comment: I found 2 other gitconfig files in ~/.npm/git-config/0.0.6/package/test/fixtures and ~/node_modules/git-config/test/fixtures I edited them as shown in my original question. Still doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: @Opera yes https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-0-129-0-fails-to-install-atom-beautify-npm-error/12182/6 shows that it should work.

Comment: @Opera https://discuss.atom.io/t/open-on-github-branch-compare-fails-if-you-have-insteadof-aliases/12177/2 would explain the issue. Or https://discuss.atom.io/t/build-atom-fails-windows-8-1/12072/2.

Comment: @Opera look for a cache.js, as instructed in https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/106

Comment: at [npm/issues/5257](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5257#issuecomment-60404802) it is also suggested to use `git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:`

Comment: @Opera did you find the issue in, for instance, the `cache.js` file?

Comment: I edited the add-remote-git.js file (now containing the code that is referred to in https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/106) and added the replace call suggested in the last comment